# Good way to copy a std:set<int32_t> to a std::set<uint32_t>

Tags: c++, stl

There is an implicit conversion available between uint32_t and int32_t.  I was a little surprised to find that I could not say:

```
void somefunc(std::set<uint32_t> arg);

std::set<int32_t> ary1;
somefunc(ary1);
```

Why is this? Is there a short-and-sweet syntax to do it without writing out a for loop to copy the first int32_t array into a temporary uint32_t array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard containers can generally be constructed using ranges from other containers, specified by pairs of iterators. Consider the following example :

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <set>

void foo(std::set<uint32_t> arg) {}

int main()
{
    std::set<int32_t> x;
    foo({ x.begin(), x.end() });
}
```

`foo` expects a `std::set<uint32_t>` but `x` is a `std::set<int32_t>`. `{x.begin(), x.begin()}` is creating a new temporary `std::set<uint32_t>` which copies all the values from `x`. It's similar to `std::set<uint32_t>(x.begin(), x.end())` that you might find in older code. This also works between different kinds of containers, provided the  contained elements are compatible.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Very clean.  I will "accept" the answer as soon as the site allows me to.

Comment: Just to be clear, you still effectively make a *copy* of your set. It's just the syntax that is concise.